# mdadm raid 1 to raid 0 (or lvm...)

Tags: 15.04, raid, lvm, mdadm

I currently have a machine with 2x3TB in software raid 1 (mdadm, Ubuntu 15.04). I would prefer to keep the data on the disks, but I can risk losing it.
Are there any options to migrate without reinstall to a 6TB configuration (raid0, lvm...)?

Answer (score 0):

For reference, I ended up failing the 2nd disk, formatting and reinstalling with an lvm partition. I stopped the array, and retrieved data from the ext4 partition (not the raid device).
Then I migrated the content to the lvm partition, formatted the 1st disk, and extending the lvm.

There was probably an easier way to go (migrating the OS partition for example), but it worked out just fine.